# GCP - how to change the IP on a VM with 2 NICs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a VM with 2 NICs. For all intents and purposes, it's a VPN server that takes connection requests on one interface and then forwards traffic out to the other interface.

Periodically, I need to change the IP on the second interface, which is easily done via the web interface. I'd like to make this change using GCP scripting tools to make the process less manual.

I have managed to automate all steps except updating the access-config. This is because both interfaces have the same access-config name ("External NAT"). I've been unable to find a way to rename or recreate this access-config name, nor have I found any workaround.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: ##.##.##.##
    networkTier: STANDARD
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  fingerprint: ==========
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic0
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#######/global/networks/inbound
  networkIP: 10.#.#.#
  subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#######/regions/northamerica-northeast1/subnetworks/inbound
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: ##.##.##.##
    networkTier: STANDARD
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  fingerprint: =========
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic1
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#######/global/networks/outbound
  networkIP: 10.0.2.3
  subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#######/regions/northamerica-northeast1/subnetworks/outbound
```

Comment: Have you already tried using this?  
[gcloud compute instances update-access-config](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/update-access-config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe (!?) [really am not **certain**] that you must delete and then create; you can't update an existing access config to change the IP using `gcloud`.

Someone else please confirm!

**PLEASE** try this on a sacrificial instance **before** you use it on the production instance

Thus:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
ZONE=[[YOUR-ZONE]]
INSTANCE=[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
INTERFACE=[[YOUR-INTERFACE]] # Perhaps "nic1"

# Show what we have currently
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="yaml(networkInterfaces)"

# Delete the "External NAT" for ${INTERFACE}
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--network-interface=${INTERFACE} \
--access-config-name="External NAT"

# Show what we have currently **without** "External NAT" for ${INTERFACE}
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="yaml(networkInterfaces)"

# Create a new "External NAT" for ${INTERFACE}
# Include --address=ADDRESS if you have one
gcloud compute instances add-access-config ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--network-interface=${INTERFACE} \
--access-config-name="External NAT"

# Show what we have currently with a **new** "External NAT" for ${INTERFACE}
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="yaml(networkInterfaces)"
```

#### Update

This was bugging me.

You can filter in the describe commands by `${INTERACE}` value:

```sh
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="yaml(networkInterfaces[].filter(name:${INTERFACE})"
```

Because `gcloud` has proprietary filtering|formatting, it's often better to format as JSON and then use `jq`. Using `jq`, we can filter by `${INTERFACE}` and return only the 'External NAT` access config:

```sh
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="json" \
jq -r ".networkInterfaces[]|select(.name==\"${INTERFACE}\")|.accessConfigs[]|select(.name==\"External NAT\")"
```

Comment: I'm quite certain that you are correct - editing access-config seems to be impossible.

Comment: And, I highly recommend your strategy of using `gcloud` for automation. It is an excellent, well-document and complete tool.

Comment: A quick follow up: while your solution didn't achieve what I had hoped to do, I was able to solve my problem based on the syntax in your response. I didn't know about the `--network-interface` setting on delete-access-config and once I had that it was simple enough to take care of the rest. Thank you!

Comment: Disappointed to learn that I misunderstood your question. Please consider answering your own question and include what you did. This will be available for posterity.

Comment: Please don't be disappointed - your response set me on the path to solving the problem. I will absolutely post the solution once I've fully-tested it. There are few things worse than finding an incorrect or misleading solution on the internet.